# Existence of absolute maxima and minima

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

In which of the following functions can be guaranteed the existence of absolute maxima and minima?

a) $f(x,y,z)=x+y$ with $z\geq x^2+y^2+1$.

b) $f(x,y)=\ln (x^2+y^2+1)$, with $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$.

c) $f(x,y)=\dfrac{xy}{x^2+(y-2)^2}$ with $x^2+y^2\leq 1$.

d) $f(x,y)=2(x^2+y^2)$ with $x^2+y^2> 1$.

Do I have to find the critical points and see if they belongs to the set given? If so, I get that the critical points of each functions are:

a) It does not have critical points

b) $(0,0)$

c) $(0,0)$

d) $(0,0)$

But I do not see what else to do.

Comment: In c) you can use that continuous function on a compact set always has a maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 1):

a) $Im(f)$ is unbounded, so no absolute min/max.

b) $Im(f)=[0, \infty)$ the absolute minimum is $0$ but there is no max.

c) The image of a continuous real function defined on a compact set is compact so there is an absolute max and min.

d) the absolute max/min doesn't exist because $Im(f)=(2, \infty)$

Comment: Thank you Eugen, so there will be more than one alternative, right? The problem is that you have to choose just one. So I must supposed that the question is wrong.

Comment: There is no maximum in (b), so (c) is the answer.

Comment: @John So you want both,min and max, therefore only c) remains